# Is it possible to make a UITextField without rounded edges?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitextfield, rounded-corners

Rounded edges are getting kind of old, and I want my program to have a modern edge. Any idea how this can be done?

To clarify: I want the exact functionality of UITextField ***without*** rounded corners.

EDIT: Sorry, I'm a dumbass. I couldn't find the button because the textbox wasn't selected.

{insert facepalm emoticon here}

Answer (score 8):

Just to help anyone who still runs into this, since it isn't clear enough you can use the Storyboard/Xib Interface Builder:

[image]

Comment: `UITextBorderStyleNone` unfortunately loses the nice interior padding that the rounded rect text fields get.

Answer (score 2):

You can just change the borderStyle property of your UITextfield, or provide your own background image by setting backgroundImage property, here is a ref [UITextField reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html)

Answer (score 1):

Subclass UITextfield and override the **drawrect:** method. I think this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify a standard UITextView created in Interface Builder in viewDidLoad as follows:

```
[_textField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
[_textField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

This can also be set the border style and background color directly in Interface Builder.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set a background image and the background color.

```
UITextField *txtSearchField = [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
[txtSearchField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[txtSearchField setBackground:[[UIImage alloc]init]];
```

Comment: Funny I got a down vote with no comment attached, how does that help anyone? Furthermore, this code works..

Comment: This is an ugly hack which will sooner or later break your app. I guess that's why you have the downvote.